# How do I make a variable randomly equal 1 of 2 numbers? (Processing)

Tags: processing

I'm trying for the first time to make Pong. I don't always want the ball to go to the bottom right by adding 3 every single time. How would I make it so it will either do 3, or -3, but no number in between? I know that "||" doesn't work for integers, and "random(-3,3) has the chance of giving me numbers like "0.1" which wouldn't really function in here. 
Code:

```java
float circleX = 640/2;
float circleY = 360/2;
float xSpeed = 3;
float ySpeed = 3;
float Color = (255);
float circleHeight = 32;
float circleWidth = 32;
float xAcceleration = -1.0;
float yAcceleration = -1.0;
float paddleColor = 255;
float MyPaddleX = 630;
float OpPaddleX = 10;
float MyPaddleWidth = 10;
float OpPaddleWidth = -10;


void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  //Ball
  fill(Color);
  ellipse(circleX, circleY, circleWidth, circleHeight);
  xSpeed = //(WHAT TO PUT HERE?)
  circleX = circleX + xSpeed;
  circleY = circleY + ySpeed;

 //My Paddle
 fill(paddleColor);
 rect(MyPaddleX,mouseY,MyPaddleWidth,100);

  //Bouncing
  if (circleX >= OpPaddleX && OpPaddleX + OpPaddleWidth >= circleX) {
    xSpeed = xSpeed * xAcceleration;
  }
  // Top/Bottom Bouncing
  if (circleY > height || circleY < 0) {
    ySpeed = ySpeed * yAcceleration;
  }
  //My Paddle Bounceback
  if (circleY >= mouseY && circleY <= mouseY + 100) {
    if (circleX >= MyPaddleX && circleX <= MyPaddleX + 3)
    xSpeed = xSpeed * xAcceleration;

  }
  //Opponent Paddle
  fill(paddleColor);
  rect(OpPaddleX,circleY - 50,OpPaddleWidth,100);

  //if (circleX < OpPaddleX || circleX > MyPaddleX) {
  //  circleX = width/2;
  //  circleY = height/2;
  //  xSpeed = 0;
  //  ySpeed = 0;
  //}

}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yes i did, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a number between `0` and `1` and then compare that generated number to `0.5` to "flip a coin" in your code.

Think about it this way: when you call `random(1)`, you'll get a value between `0` and `1`. Half of those values will be less than `0.5`, the other half will be greater than (or equal to) `0.5`.

So you can do something like this:

```
float x;

if(random(1) < .5){
  x = -3;
}
else{
  x = 3;
}
```

You could expand this to choose from more numbers using `else if` statements, or you could shorten it into a single line of code using the ternary operator:

```
float x = random(1) < .5 ? 3 : -3;
```